# No keyboard response when in Xcode breakpoint (Mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, breakpoints

I've just encountered a really bizarre scenario and can't find any info on this elsewhere.  When Xcode breaks at my breakpoints, all keyboard entry for the whole system is unresponsive.  I can switch to another app but no key strokes are recorded.  Xcode itself is unresponsive to keyboard input.

Anybody else seen this?

I'm running 10.10.1 and Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Does your app use a Quartz event tap or something like that?

Comment: No but I tracked this down a bit further.  I'm trying to debug an action triggered by a menu event.  The debugger works as expected when the menu action fires but my action opens an NSOpenPanel using beginWithCompletionHandler: – as soon as I try to break in the completion handler I can't use the keyboard (system-wide). All calls triggered from this handler appear to have the same consequence.  Outside of this, the debugger is behaving as expected (as are all other apps).

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? If so, the open panel is run by the Powerbox, not your app. Not sure how that might interact.

Comment: Yes it is.  That is a very interesting insight and a likely culprit I suppose.  It gets even more interesting when you look at the execution path of my code after the NSOpenPanel.  My NSOpenPanel completion block creates an NSOperation and enqueues it on a background NSOperationQueue (ie. not main thread). The execution of the background operation is where I initially found this issue.  So if Powerbox is the culprit it's affects are felt outside of the direct execution stream.  Maybe the execution is too quick and Powerbox hasn't released control over all input devices...?  Grasping at ideas.

Comment: You can try debugging a non-sandboxed build of your app. Or you could debug via different means, such as sprinkling log statements around the code or using DTrace.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I've been having it happen to me as well. Not sure if its relevant or not, but my breakpoints are in c code rather than objective-c code.

Comment: I worked around it using other forms of debugging (similar to what Ken recommended).  I also found that since the pointer (mouse / trackpad) still worked I could interrogate objects that appeared in the variable list by right clicking and selecting print description.  Frustrating but enough to debug so far...

Comment: Nearly 10 years later, I'm experiencing the exact same issue in Xcode 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments above it would seem that this issue has to do with behind the scenes details of Powerbox.  To explain further: my app is sandboxed and calls NSOpenPanel.  When breaking (Xcode breakpoint) in the completion block of NSOpenPanel I experience system-wide keyboard input loss.

Keyboard entry behaves normally in breakpoints outside of the call to NSOpenPanel.  After working past this area of code I observed that my subsequent operations (queued in the background from the completion bock) often finish before the NSOpenPanel is completely torn down (disappears from the screen).  My assumption is that until NSOpenPanel is removed from the screen (and maybe further after), Powerbox won't release control of the keyboard.

Much of this is assumption since I don't have the actual Powerbox code and can't step into it but it seems to fit.

I worked around my debugging issues by utilizing print statements and stepping through code with the variable inspector open.  Mouse input continues to function so you can right-click (if you have a two-button mouse) on the variable and print its description at least.

Thanks for the help Ken.

**UPDATE**
I am now delaying execution of any of my post-NSOpenPanel actions using dispatch_after.  On my system a delay of 1 second is doing the trick.  I really don't like adding arbitrary delays but this seems to work.